# How can I make use of Error boundaries in functional React components?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

I can [make a class an error boundary](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html) in React by implementing `componentDidCatch`.

Is there a clean approach to making a functional component into an error boundary without converting it into a class?

Or is this a code smell?

Comment: So, `componentDidCatch` is probably considered part of the React lifecycle hooks, which is not available in simple function components.  The only way I imagine you could do something similar would be to wrap the entirety of your function body in a [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block...

Comment: A note about Alexander's comment: there is a difference between error boundaries and try/catch: when you write <Comp/> ... Comp is not rendered yet, the expression only constructs the JSX tree. Doing a try { <Comp /> } catch { ... } will not catch any Comp render error because there is no rendering yet

Comment: Now react version is `17.01` and still, they say `Only class components can be error boundaries`

Comment: React 18 has been released, and still they say the same :-(

Answer (score 115):

As of v16.2.0, there's no way to turn a functional component into an error boundary.

[The React docs are clear about that](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries), although you're free to reuse them as many times as you wish:

> The `componentDidCatch()` method works like a JavaScript `catch {}` block, but for components. **Only class components can be error boundaries. In practice, most of the time you’ll want to declare an error boundary component once and use it throughout your application.**

Also bear in mind that `try/catch` blocks *won't work on all cases*.
If a component deep in the hierarchy tries to updates and fails, the `try/catch` block in one of the parents won't work -- because it isn't necessarily updating together with the child.

Comment: so what is your recommended alternative?

Answer (score 25):

There is an implementation that can handle with non-existent functionalities for a functional component such as `componentDidCatch` and `deriveStateFromError`.

According to the author, it is based on React.memo().

> The proposed solution is greatly inspired by the new React.memo() API.

```js
import Catch from "./functional-error-boundary"

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

const MyErrorBoundary = Catch(function MyErrorBoundary(props: Props, error?: Error) {
  if (error) {
    return (
      <div className="error-screen">
        <h2>An error has occured</h2>
        <h4>{error.message}</h4>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>
  }
})
```

reference and API [here](https://gist.github.com/andywer/800f3f25ce3698e8f8b5f1e79fed5c9c)

Answer (score 24):

As mentioned already, the React team has [not yet implemented a hook equivalent](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes), and there are [no published timelines](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19630#issuecomment-675390931) for a hook implementation.

A few third party packages on npm implement error boundary hooks. I published [react-use-error-boundary](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-error-boundary), attempting to recreate an API similar to [useErrorBoundary from Preact](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/hooks/#useerrorboundary):

```
import { withErrorBoundary, useErrorBoundary } from "react-use-error-boundary";

const App = withErrorBoundary(({ children }) => {
  const [error, resetError] = useErrorBoundary(
    // You can optionally log the error to an error reporting service
    (error, errorInfo) => logErrorToMyService(error, errorInfo)
  );

  if (error) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{error.message}</p>
        <button onClick={resetError}>Try again</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <div>{children}</div>;
});
```

Answer (score 17):

What I have done is create custom `class component` and wrapped my `functional/class` component inside it where ever its required. This is how my custom class component looks like:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {error: ""};
  }

  componentDidCatch(error) {
    this.setState({error: `${error.name}: ${error.message}`});
  }

  render() {
    const {error} = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return (
        <div>{error}</div>
      );
    } else {
      return <>{this.props.children}</>;
    }
  }
}
```

And used it like this my `functional/class` components:

```
<ErrorBoundary key={uniqueKey}>
   <FuncationalOrChildComponent {...props} />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

PS: As usual the key property is very important as it will make sure to re-render the `ErrorBoundary` component if you have dynamic child elements.

Answer (score 13):

Official React team not provided Error boundary support for functional component.
We can achieve error boundary for functional component using npm package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary

Answer (score 3):

There are some great third party libraries for this but if you are already using Sentry then you can use `Sentry.ErrorBoundary`

[docs](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/features/error-boundary/)

```js
import React from "react";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react";

<Sentry.ErrorBoundary fallback={<p>An error has occurred</p>}>
  <Example />
</Sentry.ErrorBoundary>;
```

or as a higher order component

```js
import React from "react";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react";

Sentry.withErrorBoundary(Example, { fallback: <p>an error has occurred</p> });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are coming to this page in 2023, are using TypeScript and do not want to implement a dependency there is a pretty simple but effective example over on Netlify of how to implement a simple error boundary.

Sadly there is still no functional solution to the problem as per the react docs.

Netlify example: https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/error_boundaries/