# Is there a way to prevent a broken react render from crashing the whole page?

Tags: reactjs

If a breaking error occurs in a React component, the whole page crashes. For instance, if `x` is null and you try to access `x.someProperty`, you'll get an error and the whole page will go white. This is a little bit different from an old-style app that isn't running entirely on JS, because the markup (HTML&CSS) would still be there even if the JS errored out and blocked some aspects of the page.

Is there a way to mitigate this with React? Something like wrapping a component in a try/catch so that if something goes wrong, *only* that component fails and only that part of the page goes white, rather than the entire page. I'm not sure if there's a better pattern than literally wrapping the entire body of a functional component's code in a try/catch.

I suppose I'm particularly interested in functional components here, but a class-based answer might be useful for someone else.

Comment: You can use [ErrorBoundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mitigate such errors using [Error Boundaries](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#catching-rendering-errors-with-an-error-boundary) - such components may catch errors thrown from the child components and display some meaningful error instead of just crashing.

Comment: Wow, I've never encountered this! So you create an error boundary by defining `static getDerivedStateFromError()` or `componentDidCatch()`. Kind of interesting-- so there's no standard ErrorBoundary component, and everyone creates their own? Edit: ah, yeah, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482619/how-can-i-make-use-of-error-boundaries-in-functional-react-components) re: functional components basically says as much.

Comment: Hey Jakub, the link you sent is now deprecated. Here is the new one. Thanks for the help 
https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#catching-rendering-errors-with-an-error-boundary